# MVC Get Content Belonging to Current User

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.net Identity and have a model that includes a UserID in it:

```
 public class Response
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }
        public string Userid { get; set; }
        public int Ftes { get; set; }
        public int Members { get; set; }
        public decimal Assets { get; set; }
        public decimal Budget { get; set; }
        public string Govbody { get; set; }
}
```

As well as a table that includes a responseid in it:

```
public class Basiclife
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ResponseId { get; set; }
    public string Plantype { get; set; }
    public int Enrolledftes { get; set; }
    public decimal Pctemployer { get; set; }
    public decimal Fixedbenamt { get; set; }
    public decimal Salarymult { get; set; }
    public decimal Bencap { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to add a Basiclife record and set the Id equal to the currently logged in user's responseId (each user will have only one Response):

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateBasicLifeResponse(IEnumerable<BasicLifeResponseViewModel> response)
        {
            string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            Response response = db.response.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Userid = currentUserId);
            int responseid = response.Id;


            foreach(var y in response)
            {
                Basiclife blr = new Basiclife();
                blr.ResponseId = responseid;
                /*
                 * the rest of the required BasicLife fields
                 * */

            }

            return View();
        }
```

I'm getting the error "Cannot implicitly convert type string to bool on the line `Response response = db.response.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Userid = currentUserId);`

Given that all userids are strings, I'm not sure why it's trying to convert to bool.

Comment: You need to use `FirstOrDefault(x => x.Userid == currentUserId)` (single `=` is for **assignment**). I voted to close question as "Typographic error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an equals sign:

```
Response response = db.response.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Userid == currentUserId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put equal.you should use it as follows.

Wrong(that you use) => `db.response.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Userid == currentUserId);`

Correct(should be) => `db.response.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Userid == currentUserId);`

FirstOrDefault only gets boolean.

Comment: Not sure you have copied/pasted this correctly, the first line of code should surely have '=' not '=='?